# Using index arrays vs iterating in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have many numpy arrays of about 50K elements.  I want to compare them, using only certain positions of them (10% of them in the average), and performance matters.  This looks like a good use case for index arrays.  I can write this code:

```py
def equal_1(array1, array2, index):
    return (array1[index] == array2[index]).all():
```

That is fast in practice, but it iterates for all indexes once per array.

I can use this other approach too:

```py
def equal_2(array1, array2, index):
    for i in index:
        if array1[i] != array2[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

This only iterates arrays until a difference is found.

I benchmarked both approaches for my use case.

In arrays that are equal, or where differences are at the end, the index array function is about 30 times faster.  When there are differences at the beginning of the array, the second function is about 30 times faster.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds (numpy speed + second function laziness)?

Comment: What does `index` look like? Is it an array itself?

Comment: As mentioned by @pshep123 : For collections, you should use plural variable names to make your code clearer.

Comment: You need to take advantage of 'short circuited' evaluation at the compiled code level. Numpy does that when doing things like min/max and `np.nan`

Comment: @pshep123, `index` would be a narray of indexes valid for array1 and array2.  In my typical use case, it contains something between 5K and 10K elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes, you may want to use the just-in-time compiler `@jit` from `numba`.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

a1 = np.arange(50000)
a2 = np.arange(50000)
# set some values to evaluation as false
a2[40000:45000] = 1
indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(50000), replace=False, size=5000)
indices.sort()

def equal_1(array1, array2, index):
    return (array1[index] == array2[index]).all()

def equal_2(array1, array2, index):
    for i in index:
        if array1[i] != array2[i]:
            return False
    return True

@jit  #just as this decorator to your function
def equal_3(array1, array2, index):
    for i in index:
        if array1[i] != array2[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

testing:

```
In [44]: %%timeit -n10 -r1
    ...: equal_1(a1,a2,indices)
    ...:
10 loops, best of 1: 72.6 µs per loop

In [45]: %%timeit -n10 -r1
    ...: equal_2(a1,a2,indices)
    ...:
10 loops, best of 1: 657 µs per loop

In [46]: %%timeit -n10 -r1
    ...: equal_3(a1,a2,indices)
    ...:
10 loops, best of 1: 7.65 µs per loop
```

Just by adding `@jit` you can get a ~100x speed up in your python operation.

Comment: For the record, the speed up in my tests from equal_1 to equal_3 was something in between 3 and 4 times faster for the version that uses numba,jit.  Not bad at all.